# cucmber eclipse plugin in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, eclipse-oxygen

Im not able to install cucumber plugin in eclipse oxygen - version 4.7.3a

Getting below error,

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.editor_0.0.22.201806032001.jar.
https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.editor_0.0.22.201806032001.jar
Artifact not found: https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration_0.0.22.201806032001.jar.
https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration_0.0.22.201806032001.jar
Artifact not found: https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.steps.jdt_0.0.22.201806032001.jar.
https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/plugins/cucumber.eclipse.steps.jdt_0.0.22.201806032001.jar

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the zip file from [git hub link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/tree/master/cucumber.eclipse.download/download) and installed manually to the eclipse. This works. Hope helps others.